# C++ - Passing a function pointer taking const argument to a template class is wrongly interpeted

Tags: c++, templates, callback, void-pointers

So, I have a template class, which must call a callback function at some time. That callback function takes `const T` template as an argument.

I pass that function's pointer to a template class `Boom<void*>`. However, the `const T` argument of that callback is interpreted as just `T`.

But this is the case only with `void*`.

The code:

```
//main.cpp

void kolbek(const void* val)
{
    if(val)
        printf("Value is: %d\n", *((int*)val));
    else
        printf("Value ptr = NULL\n");
}

int main()
{
    Boom<void*> bomba;
    bomba.setCallback(kolbek); //error!

    int* nuint = new int(5);
    bomba.callCallback((void*)nuint);
    delete nuint;

    return 0;
}
```

//boom.h

```
template<typename T>
class Boom
{
private:
    void (*someCallback)(const T) = nullptr;
public:
    Boom(){ }
    ~Boom(){ }

    void setCallback(void (*callbk)(const T));
    void callCallback(const T val);
};
```

//boom.cpp

```
template<typename T>
void Boom<T>::setCallback(void (*callbk)(const T))
{
    this->someCallback = callbk;
}

template<typename T>
void Boom<T>::callCallback(const T val)
{
    if(someCallback)
        (*someCallback)(val);
    else
        printf("Bad! Callback's NULL!\n");
}

template class Boom<int>;
template class Boom<void*>;
```

And when trying to compile this, an error is thrown:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(const void*)' to 'void (*)(void*)' [-fpermissive]
error: initializing argument 1 of 'void Boom<T>::setCallback(void (*)(T)) [with T = void*]' [-fpermissive]
```

How to fix it? Seems like only void* pointers are wrongly interpreted.

Comment: first of all you cannot create implementation of your templates inside cpp file, as they won't be linked... move your boom.cpp content to your boom.h file

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg - that's not true. He explicitly instantiates two types - Boom<int> and Boom<void*>. If they are the types he needs elsewhere then they'll link just fine

Comment: secondly your compiler see your templated method parameter callbk as `void * const` rather than `const void *`

Comment: @Smeeheey will it? I've never experiment with such model, but probably you're right...

Comment: To make it work as you expected just remove constness from your template and change your usage to: `Boom<const void *> b;`

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg - yes it will, that's the whole point of the  [explicit instantiation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation) lines

Comment: @Smeeheey nice trick, but kills genericity of the approach... :)

Comment: @Wojciech Frohmberg But I need it to use as `Boom<void*>`, and not  `Boom<const void *>`. I only need `const` at that specific callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from confusing two different `const`s. This is why it can be helpful to write `T const` instead of `const T` - it makes textual substitution not lie to you.

`Boom`'s callback takes a `T const` which in your instatiation is `void* const` (not `const void*`!!): it's a `const` pointer to non-`const` `void`. `kolbek`'s argument takes a `void const*` - a pointer to `const void`. Those aren't the same type. You can do a qualification conversion from the former to the latter, but not the other way around (you'd be casting away `const`!). This is your compiler error.

The simplest solution is not not have `Boom` add `const`. It's unnecessary. Use the `T` as provided and use `Boom<const void*>`.

Comment: I proposed the solution with `Boom<const void*>` in a comment, but OP stated that he/she uses the `T` parameter more than once in the `Boom` implementation and one time it should be `const` and in the others shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

In the case mentioned in comment you could create helper struct to make your template dereferenced parameter const:

```
template<class T>
struct ptr_constantizer {
 using type = const T;
};

template<class T>
struct ptr_constantizer<T*> {
 using type = const T*;
};

template<typename T>
class Boom
{
private:
    void (*someCallback)(typename ptr_constantizer<T>::type) = nullptr;
public:
    Boom(){ }
    ~Boom(){ }

    void setCallback(void (*callbk)(typename ptr_constantizer<T>::type)) { }
    void callCallback(const T val) { }
};

void foo(const void *ptr) {
}
void fooi(const int non_ptr) {
}

int main() {
   Boom<void *> b;
   Boom<int> bi;
   b.setCallback(&foo);
   bi.setCallback(&fooi);
}
```

The code assumes you are using `c++11` as you used `nullptr` in your example...